# CreateSeuratObject issue in R - when first column is gene names it states '0 features across X samples'

Tags: r, seurat

I'm completely new to the analysis of scRNA data and have been having issues with the CreateSeuratObject command in R.

Essentially, I have the gene expression matrix in a csv file named X with the first row being cells, and the first column being ENSG gene codes, and the number of counts expressed within the matrix.

The gene names are in ENSG format so I have merged this data frame with a geneID data frame, and then deleted the ENSG column using the following code.

```
X <- merge(X, geneidname, by.x="V1", by.y="gene_id")
X<-X[,c(19144, 1:19143)] 
X$V1 <- NULL
```

The end result is a matrix where the first column is the gene matrix and the first row are the cells, with count data in the corresponding place in the matrix.

However, when I try to create the seurat object using

```
`X_seurat <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = X, project = "X_seurat", min.cells = 5)
```

The end result is
An object of class Seurat
0 features across X samples within 1 assay
Active assay: RNA (0 features, 0 variable features)

However, when get rid of the first column using code X <-X[,-1] and then try to repeat creation of the SeuratObject again it works, giving me
An object of class Seurat
XXX features across 19142 samples within 1 assay
Active assay: RNA (XXX features, 0 variable features)

I'm super confused by this. Why am I not able to create the seuratObject with the gene name column included. I've checked and the gene name column class is 'character' and the rest of the columns class are 'integers'. It seems a bit counter-intuitive to me that the gene names should be deleted to be able to create the Seurat Object and I've clearly gone wrong somewhere - can anybody help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to provide the genes and the cells as `rownames()` and `colname()`. That's why your second attempt works. If you convert the first  column to rownames and the first row to colnames, it should work just fine.